# a VPS mail server

Tags: email, email-server

Hello I'm trying to substitute [citadel](http://www.citadel.org/doku.php) on my Virtual Private Server with something more simple. I dislike their documentation and the webmail client. I don't need any groupware feature. I need only an MTA with a nice looking web interface, SPAM and VIRUS check.

I recently found the [lamson](http://lamsonproject.org/) project from Zed Shaw. Is that production ready? Do you had any real and good experience with It? On the latest-news page I see that the [last release dates december 2009](http://lamsonproject.org/blog/).

Sorry for my lack of knowledge, I'm really new to mail servers but I have to find a solution to manage sending and receiving mail on my VPS.

I would accept also to build my VPS email server using a linux system like exim, postfix or whatever but I have really small needs and they will not grow in at least a year and i will be the only one user. I'm searching for something that I could build and manage easily, as I'm a novice linux sysadmin. Having also some good documentation or at least a robust step by step guide would be a plus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is Gmail a nice enough webmail client?

Google offers Google Apps For Your Domain, where they host mail for your own domain name (i.e. you can use **microspino.com** instead of **gmail.com**).

Your web interface is Gmail, but customized with your domain name and logo. You don’t need a server. You use Google’s SMTP and spam filtering. If you prefer, you can access your mail using IMAP or POP3.

And if that isn’t enough, you also get ActiveSync support for your mobile phone.

[Google Apps Standard Edition](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html) is **free** for up to 50 users.